# Synthetic classes in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a number of tables in my DB, called

```
UserMatchCriteria
UserMatchLifestyle
UserHobby
```

Now the first two have a single line entry per User Id, but the third table can contain anywhere from 0 to 100 entries depending on the hobbies the user has chosen.

I want to be able in C# code to have an object called something like UserSearchDetails, which contains a single UserMatchCriteria object, a single UserMatchLifestyle object and an IList collection which contains zero or more UserHobby objects.

My problem is I dont want to tie the User table into having to be linked to these on every load, as that is a large overhead that I will almost never need with all the use cases I have for a User Object. I want the search details to be loaded separately in a UserSearchDetails object, which has no DB table associated with it. Obviously I can use NHibernate to do things such as

```
<one-to-one name=UserMatchCriteria>
<one-to-one name=UserMatchLifestyle>
<bag name=Hobbies........... />
```

etc, but without a base table to run the initial select off, and to provide me with the UserId, Im not sure in what context to use these entries.

Do I need to create another table called UserSearchDetails with just a single entry for UserId in, to use as my base table that then joins on other tables via the PK of the UserId?

Or is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

the references and the bag are lazy loaded by default. you could map a component in the user

```
<component name="UserSearchDetails">
  <many-to-one>
  <many-to-one>
  <bag>
<component>
```